# Capping a value in Excel using data validation

Tags: excel

Wonder if someone can help?

I'm trying to cap a mark for an assignments spreadsheet if it is submitted late, or the attempt is more than 1. One exception is that it is submitted late, however their assignment was "Accepted - Late". I have checked all the references and all seem to be OK. It is not capping if G4 is blank but E4 is larger than F4, but it should and I can't see why it won't here.

As far as I can tell:

(is the work late (E4>F4)
AND is it Accepted late) if so, keep below 101, if not check if the work is late, if it is late then cap at 50, if not, check if attempt is more than 1, if it is cap at 50, if not cap at 101.

```
=IF(AND($E4>$F4, $G4="Accepted - Late"), $J4<101, IF($E4>$F4, $J4<51, IF($B4>1, $J4<51, $J4<101)))
```

Comment: It seems that if G4 has any value in whatsoever, it applies the less than 101 rule, but if it's blank no rule at all is applied?

Comment: It looks like B4 is the number of attempts, E4 is the date it arrived, F4 is the date it was due, and G4 is a late waiver. What is J4?

Comment: Thanks Dev1998 - J4 is the actual mark inputted, so that should be capped at 100 if standard submission, or if late or 2nd/3rd attempt capped at 50

Comment: @dev1998 above for you, sorry forgot to tag

Answer (score 0):

After changing some formatting, this seemed to work, note some columns moved around.

```
=IF(AND($D3>$E3, F3="Accepted - Late"),  $I3<101,IF(K3>1, $I3<41, IF($D3>$E3, $I3<41,$I3<101)))
```